# Simple derivation of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let **$x$** $=(x_1, x_2, x_3)'$, and $u(x)=3x_1^3 -2x_1^2x_2+4x_3$. Find$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

So far I have done a simple differentiation and got

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
9x_1^2-4x_1x_2+4x_3 \\
3x_1^3-2x_1^2+4x_3 \\
3x_1^3-2x_1^2x_2+4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have doubts and I think I am under-thinking this. Does anyone have any advice if I am missing anything?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We we compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}$, we view the other two variables $x_2, x_3$ as constants. So
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(3x_1^3)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(2x_1^2x_2)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}(4x_3)=9x_1^2-4x_1x_2+\color{red}{0}.$$
For the same reason, we have
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}(3x_1^3)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}(2x_1^2x_2)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}(4x_3)=\color{red}{0}-2x_1^2+\color{red}{0},$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}(3x_1^3)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}(2x_1^2x_2)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}(4x_3)=\color{red}{0}+\color{red}{0}+4.$$

Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\text{(It is more common to denote it by $\nabla u$)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
9x_1^2-4x_1x_2 \\
-2x_1^2 \\
4 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ah, a rookie mistake! I got carried away worrying if a row-by-row differentiation was correct that I overlooked basic differentiation! Thank you very much for pointing it out to me!

Comment: @a9302c  You're welcome. I'm glad to help.  :-)